# Set a different input method for each app window

Tags: kde, opensuse, locale

Is there a way in KDE to set a different input method for each app window? For example, for coding I use one input method (english), but at the same time I chat in Skype window using my native language, and it's annoying each time to switch languages.

P.S. I'm using KDE 4.10.5 (openSUSE 12.3)

P.P.S. In Windows this is called "Let me set a different input method for each app window".

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pss... In KDE there is an option that do the same.

> See the keyboard layout configuration, in the "Switching Options" tab, there's "Switching Policy".

<sub>Stealed from [this comment](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=96204#c1).</sub>

Comment: I knew there is one, just that I don't have KDE in this box.